# Backbone.Marionette onRender callback fires before view is rendered in browser?

Tags: backbone.js, settimeout, marionette

### The setting

I have Backbone.Marionette.ItemView which renders some content. When the content is rendered I'd like to apply a jQuery plugin which turns part of the view into a container with a scrollbar.

The scrollbar is implemented completely in javascript and upon initialization it has to check the height of the scroll-container as well as that of the content inside the container.

If the content is higher then the container, a scrollbar should be enabled.

### The problem

While this all sounds simple, I've ran into a strange problem:

If I initialize my scrollbar plugin directly in the onRender callback it seems to think the .scroll-container element has a height 0 and maxHeight of 0.

If I wrap the initialization code inside a 0ms timeout though, everything works as it should, the .scroll-container element's height property is returned by jQuery correctly and the scrollbar plugin works great.

### The code

```
onRender: function() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.onLayout();
    var $scrollContainer = that.$el.find('.scroll-container'), 
        scrollPane = new ScrollPane($scrollContainer, {
          maxHeightProperty: 'maxHeight',
          scrollUpButton: false,
          scrollDownButton: false
        });
  }, 0);
},
```

### The question

I'm assuming the problem occurs because the browser didn't finish actually rendering the newly inserted html when the onRender callback is executed.

Is this assumption correct? And if so, is my solution of using a 0ms timeout reliable under normal circumstances?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since the plugin in question depends on the DOM, `onRender` won't do what you need. This callback kicks off after the view has been rendered, but there is no guarantee that the view's `el` has been added to the DOM yet. In fact, you are safe assuming the opposite - that it has not been added yet.

If you're using a Marionette `Region` to show the view, you can implement an `onShow` method in your view. This method gets called by the region, after the region has added the view to the DOM. It was implemented specifically to handle this situation.

For a little more info on this, and on working with jQuery plugins in general, see this blog post: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/

Comment: Awesome, thanx! That'll do the trick. Looks much nicer then a 0ms timeout too!

Comment: Note that if you are using a Marionette view that contains regions, such as Layout, it will also have an "onShow" method that you can hook in to.

Comment: @Derick - if I attach an event listener in onShow (using $('.selector').on('...), should I unbind it in onClose?

Comment: DOM events will be cleaned up for you when the view is closed, as long as the `close` or `remove` method is called on the view instance. DOM event clean up is built in to Backbone.View's "remove" method

Comment: you can also use onAttach , it fires after onShow